# How to set Vuetify Navigation Drawer always on top of all other app components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, vuetify.js

I'd like to know how I could do this.

With some components it appears to be on top, but then other components, such like a Leaflet (Map) component, they overlaps my SideDrawer so I can't use it properly.

How could I set my navigation drawer to be always on top with a higher z-index than the other components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. open up your root component `App.vue`
2. make sure your style tag doesn't have the scoped attribute so CSS can apply globally
3. add the following CSS

```css
.v-navigation-drawer {
z-index: 999999 !important;
}
```

Comment: That was my solution. Other point that's important is to add a z-index property to the drawer child component so we'll assure that the drawer will always be on top.
Learn more about the stacking context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem with the `v-calendar` component. The navigation drawer was working for any other page than the one with `v-calendar`.

It turns out I was not using the elements `v-app`, `v-content` and `v-container` in the correct way. Could you share your `App.vue` content so we can check that?

I believe you should look for that structure rather than working on **css tricks** (not that we can't, but when working with components, we were not supposed to change that deep)

For example, in my app it works now and the structure I have is the following:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer ... />
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <router-view />
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

And the `view` with the calendar is more or less like:

```
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col>
      <v-sheet>
        <v-calendar />
      </v-sheet>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>
```

I hope it helps!